# There is an error in Xml document(19, 10) Input not correct format

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I am getting input stream not in correct format xml errors at locations in my planets.xml where there is nothing wrong.  Visual Studio 2017 4.7 framework.  WCF is installed.  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvPqj.png)(error in IDE) With using the streamreader to load the xml it gives me the error at position 19,10 which is the < of the subtype field.  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX6tg.png)(inside planets.xml)  And just now tried this with the xmlreader and the new error is position 18,35 which is the closing tag between spectral and Class (one-word).  Im lost on this, other tickets on here and the web usually you can see immediately the error in their xml file but nothing is jumping out at me for my problem.

Planets.xml (short segment, 3,146 planets)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<planets>
    <planet>
        <name>A Place</name>
        <xcood>-123.764</xcood>
        <ycood>272.182</ycood>
    </planet>
    <planet>
        <name>Abadan</name>
        <xcood>-70.319</xcood>
        <ycood>-95.949</ycood>
        <pressure>3</pressure>
        <gravity>1.03</gravity>
        <lifeForm>7</lifeForm>
        <climate>2</climate>
        <percentWater>63</percentWater>
        <temperature>22</temperature>
        <spectralClass>F</spectralClass>
        <subtype>1</subtype>
        <luminosity>V</luminosity>
        <sysPos>5</sysPos>
        <socioIndustrial>C-C-D-C-C</socioIndustrial>
        <landMass>Abadan Major (Abbasid)</landMass>
        <landMass>Abadan Minor</landMass>
        <landMass>Kuran Major</landMass>
        <landMass>Kuran Minor</landMass>
        <hpg>B</hpg>
    </planet>
</planets>
```

Planets.vb

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("planets", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class Planets

    Private planetField() As planetsPlanet

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("planet")>
    Public Property planet() As planetsPlanet()
        Get
            Return Me.planetField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.planetField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class planetsPlanet

    Private n As String
    Private x As Decimal
    Private y As Decimal
    Private a As String
    Private o As String
    Private f As String
    Private fC As planetsPlanetFactionChange
    Private p As Integer
    Private g As Decimal
    Private nC As Boolean
    Private zC As Boolean
    Private lF As Integer
    Private c As Integer
    Private pW As Integer
    Private t As Integer
    Private sC As Char
    Private sT As Integer
    Private l As Char
    Private sP As Integer
    Private sI As String
    Private s As String
    Private lM As String
    Private HPG As Char
    Private d As String

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("name", GetType(String))>
    Public Property name() As String

        Get
            Return Me.n
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.n = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("xcood", GetType(Decimal))>
    Public Property xcood() As Decimal

        Get
            Return Me.x
        End Get
        Set(value As Decimal)
            Me.x = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ycood", GetType(Decimal))>
    Public Property ycood() As Decimal

        Get
            Return Me.y
        End Get
        Set(value As Decimal)
            Me.y = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("axis", GetType(String))>
    Public Property axis() As String

        Get
            Return Me.a
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.a = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("orbit", GetType(String))>
    Public Property orbit() As String

        Get
            Return Me.o
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.o = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("faction", GetType(String))>
    Public Property faction() As String

        Get
            Return Me.f
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.f = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("factionChange", GetType(planetsPlanetFactionChange))>
    Public Property factionChange() As planetsPlanetFactionChange

        Get
            Return Me.fC
        End Get
        Set(value As planetsPlanetFactionChange)
            Me.fC = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("pressure", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property pressure() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.p
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.p = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("gravity", GetType(Decimal))>
    Public Property gravity() As Decimal

        Get
            Return Me.g
        End Get
        Set(value As Decimal)
            Me.g = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("nadirCharge", GetType(Boolean))>
    Public Property nadirCharge() As Boolean

        Get
            Return Me.nC
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.nC = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("zenithCharge", GetType(Boolean))>
    Public Property zenithCharge() As Boolean

        Get
            Return Me.zC
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.zC = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("lifeForm", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property lifeForm() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.lF
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.lF = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("climate", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property climate() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.c
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.c = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("percentWater", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property percentWater() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.pW
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.pW = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("temperature", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property temperature() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.t
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.t = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("spectralClass", GetType(Char))>
    Public Property spectralClass() As Char

        Get
            Return Me.sC
        End Get
        Set(value As Char)
            Me.sC = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("subtype", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property subtype() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.sT
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.sT = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("luminosity", GetType(Char))>
    Public Property luminosity() As Char

        Get
            Return Me.l
        End Get
        Set(value As Char)
            Me.l = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("sysPos", GetType(Integer))>
    Public Property sysPos() As Integer

        Get
            Return Me.sP
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me.sP = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("socioIndustrial", GetType(String))>
    Public Property socioIndustrial() As String

        Get
            Return Me.sI
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.sI = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("satellite", GetType(String))>
    Public Property satellite() As String

        Get
            Return Me.s
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.s = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("landMass", GetType(String))>
    Public Property landMass() As String

        Get
            Return Me.lM
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.lM = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("hpg", GetType(Char))>
    Public Property HPGStation() As Char

        Get
            Return Me.HPG
        End Get
        Set(value As Char)
            Me.HPG = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("desc", GetType(String))>
    Public Property desc() As String

        Get
            Return Me.d
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.d = value
        End Set

    End Property

End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class planetsPlanetFactionChange

    Private dateField As String

    Private factionField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property [date]() As String
        Get
            Return Me.dateField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.dateField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property faction() As String
        Get
            Return Me.factionField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.factionField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

objPlanets.vb (where I am trying to serialize the xml)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Class objPlanets

    Private Sub serialPlanets()

        Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Planets))
        Dim p As Planets
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Planets\planets.xml")
        Do While reader.Read()

            p = serial.Deserialize(reader)

        Loop
        reader.Close()

        For Each planet In p.planet()

            If planet.axis() = String.Empty Then

                planet.axis = getAxis()

            Else

                Continue For

            End If

        Next

        Using fs As New FileStream(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Planets\planets.xml", FileMode.Truncate)

            serial.Serialize(fs, p)

        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Function getAxis() As String

        Select Case roll2D6()

            Case 2 To 6

                Return "Tilted"

            Case 7 To 12

                Return "No Tilt"

            Case Else

                Return "Error"

        End Select

    End Function

    Private Function getOrbit() As String

        Select Case roll2D6()

            Case 2 To 6

                Return "Elliptical"

            Case 7 To 12

                Return "Circular"

            Case Else

                Return "Error"

        End Select

    End Function

    Private Function roll2D6() As Integer

        Dim rollResult1 As Integer = CInt((Rnd() * 5) + 1)
        Dim rollResult2 As Integer = CInt((Rnd() * 5) + 1)
        Return rollResult1 + rollResult2

    End Function

    Public Sub New()

        serialPlanets()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can simplify all your properties by just not providing the Get and Set (or End Property).  VB will create the private member for you and name it the same as your property but with a leading underscore. (e.g. Public Property Blah as String will have an implied _Blah variable created)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your XML either.  Are you sure the file you're reading is actually the same as what you're showing?

Comment: Oh, neat that is so much less to type without all the get and set'rs.  Do i even need all that serialization above each property?  I didnt have those before and added them back in (paste xml as classes makes a whole table and stuff I couldnt access) to try to make this work but, no change.  And yes I just double checked and that is the exact xml file I am telling it to read.  Its not making any sense to me.

Comment: The encoding of the xml file may be wrong.  Open the xml with notepad.  Then try doing a saveas and check encoding type in the saveas dialog box.  It should be set to utf8.

Comment: Ok, so in Notepad++ I selected the whole document and changed all tabs to spaces (4/tab) and retried, still errors on 19, 10.  Changed it to use XmlReader with settings on ignore whitespace and comments, same error.  And just now tested your suggestion @jdweng (notepad++ didnt have an encoding option when saving as) so opened with normal notepad and saved over it with UTF-8, same error occurs.  Reopened in Notepad++ and said doc was encoded in UTF-8-BOM so changed it back to UTF-8.  Im going to try saving it as text and see where that gets me.

Comment: Same error with file as planets.txt

Comment: Deleted the planet Abadan that it keeps throwing on error on the < of the subtype field and retried.  Now throws an error on line 104 column 10 which is the < of the subtype field on another planet  (the next planet after Abadan that contains the subtype field) this is something specific to that subtype tag that it doesnt like.  [link](https://i.imgur.com/Ri328as.png)(inside planets.xml)

Comment: Changed subtype to "subType" in my code and then to all 1,500+ occurrences in the xml and re-tested, same error at 19,10.  I am running out of ideas.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz2R9oe3rM_bOHZGc1FQcXRIRnc
My project XMLTest.zip

Comment: The error is on row 19, character 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the `Char` type properties.  While your xml data has a single letter in these properties it is a `String`.  The data value needs to be an integer that represents the UTF-8 character.

i.e.  `<spectralClass>F</spectralClass>` should be `<spectralClass>70</spectralClass>`

It will probably be easier to change all your `Char` type properties to `String` type.

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out after retyping the error location line and then noticing the lines immediately above and below I had set to accept Char which I guess serialization doesnt like.  Changed those to strings.

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("spectralClass", GetType(String))>
Public Property spectralClass() As String

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("subtype", GetType(Integer))>
Public Property subtype() As Integer

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("luminosity", GetType(String))>
Public Property luminosity() As String
```

Then started giving me new error positions and found out whoever entered some of the true fields for various planets sometimes were typed as "True, TRUE , or TRUE"  And it errored on those so had to change them all to true.  Now it works great writes out a more complete planets.xml for me.  Thank you guys very much now I can start making progress on this again.